# Gibberish icon loads instead of font on a specific site

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I am having problem whenever I load nextJS doc in my pc's browser. I tried firefox,edge,chrome. All of them looks like this. What should I do? Refreshing doesn't work
[image]